# How to make a chart in Views with date as x-axis (using the charts module)?

Tags: 7, views, datetime, charts

I want to make a simple view using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module.

The `x-axis` will be a custom field of type `Date` that I want to show in `Y-m-d` format and grouped by the same date. The `y-axis` will be `NID` with `COUNT` aggregation.

This seems so easy but the problem is the aggregation of the date field. Apparently, views doesn't like to aggregate those kind of fields. Tried [Views Date Format SQL](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_date_format_sql) but this only works for core date fields (Posted Date, Updated date...)

So, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Within the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, there is an interesting issue about this, i.e. [Graph node input over time (support date formatting on a continuous axis)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1237096).

In [Comment #3](https://www.drupal.org/node/1237096#comment-7697321) of that issue is stated: 'The trouble here is that neither Views nor Date modules provide aggregation options for date-based fields.'. The patch(es) included in this issue are expected to soon be applied.

Comment: That means it's not possible? So annoying!

Comment: OK, thank you for that clarification. With that consider that part "closed" (which is also why I just removed my comment about that, to indicate also "good enough, let's move on and not worry about it (anymore)", OK? Also, I plan to soon (whenever I have some time) work on an enhanced version of my answer here. If it'd take too long, feel free to "ping" me here about a possible status update, OK?

Comment: Ok. Will try to solve this in any other way.